# Ajax not working while calling php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Requirements :

1. I have created a html page - to save a group of fields into a separate file
2. Through ajax function(AjaxLoad), i have send some value into file.php and save it.
3. I can able to reach the file.php, but its not creating the file. 
    code is follows

### javascript

```
function AjaxLoad(LstrXML){
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    var url="file.php?contentd="+LstrXML;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    function stateChanged()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    function GetXmlHttpObject()
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### php

```
$fh = fopen("XML/testFile.xml", 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "<item labelText ='Age' txtBoxSize='20' optionType='*'></item><item labelText ='Gender' txtBoxSize='20' optionType='*'>";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

But its working in all browser's other than IE..What to do for compatibility?
What's the problem in it? Please guide me on this.

Thanks,
Praveen J

Comment: **@Chacha102:** I just edited the question.

Comment: Thanks ... 200 more rep till I can!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your 4th line to this would be a good idea:

```
 var url="file.php?contentd="+ escape(LstrXML)
```

Also go to your php page in a web browser manually and see if it is outputting valid XML with all tags closed and nested properly.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. now its working fine.. may i know! what is the function of "escape".. why this escape is included here.. thanks again

Comment: The "escape()" function was deprecated quite a while ago: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Predefined_Functions/Escape_and_unescape_Functions. Use encodeUriComponent instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent.

Comment: @NickFitz Oh I was unaware of that, thanks for the feedback. I will be sure to use that function instead from now on.
@praveen glad it helped, please check out Nick's comment.